# Stream file name or converting stream to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am getting System.IO.Stream object from an interface.

I want to get the path of file name from which stream is connect . As the stream will be to an excel file Or can I just read the stream and convert it into dataTable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get the filename for all streams - it has to be a FileStream :

```
    if (strm is FileStream)
    {
       FileStream fs = (FileStream)strm;
       string name = fs.Name;
    }
```

And No, you cannot convert just any stream to a DataTable. It depends on what is inside the stream.

Answer (score 1):

And if this is a memory stream and there is no file involved?

A `Stream` doesn't have source information, so you can't get this data (i.e. filename).

As for converting a `Stream` to a `DataTable` - you can load XML to a `DataTable` using the `ReadXml` method and using the constructor overload that takes a `StreamingContext`, but these wouldn't simply take an excel file.

Comment: Can I convert to Stream to DataTable ?

Comment: So if the stream is excel file and i using ReadXml method of DataTable then will dataTable will fill it self with the stream  ?

Comment: @Huzaifa - Think about that for a second. You need to provide valid XML to the method. Is the stream going to have valid XML?